# How to properly access a 'promise' value from a helper function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A few different main components in my React app use functions to retrieve data from my Firebase database.

I put these as static functions in a helper class, as such:

```
class FirebaseRetrieveHelper extends Component {
    ... (other functions)

    // Gets all PDE files, for all users
    static getAllFromAllUsers = () => {
        this.usersCollectionRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => { 
                this.userCodeCollectionRef(doc.id).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                    var items = querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {
                        data = documentSnapshot.data();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        // I can't do this:
       return data
    }
}
```

I access these functions from another component as follows:

```
class TAView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            ....
        }

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var items = FirebaseRetrieveHelper.getAllFromAllUsers();
    }

...
```

The way fetching from Firebase works, I need to use a `.then()` function, and normally one would then retrieve its value by putting in in the `state` of the corresponding class, which would be the answer to the many similar questions on promise functions in React. This wouldn't work in this case, as this is a static function from a helper class.

How might I access the response from my `.then()` function? Or is there a much better, React-y way to tackle this problem?

Comment: This isn't a React-specific thing. Since the functions get their data asynchronously, they can only *provide* that data asynchronously. You can't wrap an asynchronous process in a synchronous one. `getAllFromAllUsers` will need to return the promise chain, and then `componentWillMount` (or better, `componentDidMount`) will need to consume that promise.

Comment: Returning the promise chain is a good answer I didn't think of, thanks. I will answer my own question then.